# GCP port forwarding

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to google cloud and i am trying to setup port forwarding for my website, its basically an api i wrote but client only talks to that api thru specific port 30443, how can i setup load balancer or forward rule to accept incoming 30443 and send that to VM instance on 443? i read about iptables that you can use on ubuntu server to do this simple port forwarding but not sure if it is effective way or use load balancer

Answer (score 1):

GCP doesn't offer port forwarding unless you run your API in the Kubernetes cluster - only then you can [expose it as a service](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps) on a port you choose.

You can also run your API on a non standard ports (if it allows it) or use iptables (assuming you're running Linux) to redirect all queries from 30433 to 433.

Comment: @adrian Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?